# How to add Floating Action Button in fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, floating-action-button, user-experience

I want to implement **bottom navigation bar** in my application with different `fragments` and each `fragment` contain different `FloatingActionButton` and if i click on floating action new activity will open. it is possible?. Can anyone provide code or refer document or video any thing that help me.

Here is my app i want add FAB in it and different FAB in Different fragment:

[image]

Comment: just add FAB in every fragment you want and handle click on that fabButton to open activity

Comment: can You provide basic code ?. please...

Comment: i am new in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a YT video that explains how to create a bottom navigation.

https://youtu.be/jpaHMcQDaDg

When you are done with the creation of the bottom navigation just add a FAB in each fragment you want. With the following code in your fragment XML.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_alarm_black_24dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Also add the following dependency to your gradle.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your fragment UI xml file. add the `FloatingActionButton` where you want to show:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/submit"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

from google android documentation: [Add a Floating Action Button](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button)